# Update the data type of a string column to timestamp in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table with a column where timestamps are actually in a string format. I want to convert the datatype of this column to timestamp.

I have tried the following successfully.

```
create or replace table xyz as
select
    *,
    to_timestamp(my_time_column, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF UTC') as _my_time_column
from xyz
);

alter table xyz drop column my_time_column;

alter table xyz rename column _my_time_column to my_time_column;
```

This works well, but I find it too verbose. Is a better option available?

Answer (score 1):

This is a good solution. Recently snowflake released new sql syntax that supports `exclude` & `rename` functionality.

You can hence try this technique:

1. Create a column with correct data: `to_timestamp(my_time_column, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF UTC')` and assign some unique name -- `_my_time_column`
2. Now `exclude` the original column with `varchar` type & `rename` the above column `_my_time_column` to the actual column.
3. Wrap this entire query into a CTAS.

Sample solution:

```
create or replace table xyz as
select * exclude my_time_column rename _my_time_column as my_time_column from (
    select
        *,
        to_timestamp(my_time_column, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF UTC') as _my_time_column
    from xyz
);
```

You can read more about these new syntax in following docs:

1. Snowflake [reference](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/select.html).
2. Blog [post](https://medium.com/snowflake/snowflake-select-exclude-rename-3e9c9a4073ed).
3. Detailed [usage](https://select.dev/posts/exclude-rename).